# Sagemaker Pipeline connection to RDS times out but EC2 and Reachability Analyzer can connect? How to fix or debug?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-vpc

We have a Sagemaker Notebook created via python .ipynb file. The preprocessing step sets the `network_config` like so:

[image]

and runs the pipeline with outside network isolation:

[image]

These are private subnets in VPC "ML". We have an RDS in VPC "Prod". The pipeline logs in CloudWatch **show a timeout when trying to connect to RDS**, which has public DNS and a security group. The security group for the pipeline has outbound access to anything (and the rds sg for good measure), and the RDS sg has inbound for the pipeline sg (and the CIDR of the PeerConnection).

I created an EC2 instance on the private ML VPC subset with the pipeline SG. This could reach the RDS.

I used Reachability Analyzer to trace that instance to the local IP of RDS. It worked, labeld "Reachable", like this:

[image]

The security group and subnet of that instance are the same ones specified in the pipeline network_config.

How can I diagnose the Sagemaker Pipeline? Why will it not connect to RDS when my EC2 instance does connect? Any help would be great, thank you.

Comment: For testing, would setting `enable_network_isolation` to `False` help here?

Comment: Yes, this was it. I'm not sure if it's correct, but the connection went through to RDS.  I need to undo some security group settings to make sure I'm still at least privileges, but the pipeline ran. I pursued that network isolation route before the private VPC, and didn't go back! Please submit as an answer to collect your bounty. (Bonus points if you can explain why, which I'm still not completely sure about : )

Comment: Great! I have published an answer with some additional explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connecting AWS SageMaker Pipelines to an RDS instance involves ensuring that your network configurations are set up correctly and that the appropriate permissions and security group settings are in place.

Since you have `enable_network_isolation` set to `True` (as seen in "[Tenable Cloud Security Policies](https://www.tenable.com/policies/cloud-security/AC_AWS_0225)"), I suggested setting it to `False`, as it might be preventing the pipeline from accessing the resources outside its environment.

```py
network = NetworkConfig(
  security_group_ids=[
    "sg-04a0..."
  ],
  subnets=[
    "subnet-0b56...",
    "subnet-069..."
  ],
  enable_network_isolation=False
)
```

When `enable_network_isolation` is set to `True`, the network is isolated in such a manner that it cannot interact with other AWS services, except for downloading data from S3 and sending logs to CloudWatch.
This is designed to enhance security by ensuring that the runtime environment for the SageMaker resources is isolated from the public internet, and also from other services within your AWS environment.
It restricts all inbound and outbound network traffic, except for the minimal traffic necessary for the SageMaker service to function.

By setting `enable_network_isolation` to `False`, you disabled this strict isolation policy, allowing the necessary communication between your SageMaker Pipeline and the RDS service to occur.
It essentially permitted the SageMaker Pipeline to initiate connections to the RDS database, which was located in a different VPC, thereby solving the issue you were facing with the timeout during the connection attempt.

What remains to be done, however, is to review and potentially tighten your security group and VPC settings to maintain a secure environment while having network isolation disabled.

> I need to undo some security group settings to make sure I'm still at least privileges, but the pipeline ran.

To maintain a [principle of least privilege (PoLP)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/wellarchitected/latest/framework/sec_permissions_least_privileges.html) while allowing the necessary communication, it is indeed advisable to revisit your security group settings.

#### [Security Groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/security-groups.html):

Check your [inbound and outbound rules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/vpc-security-groups.html).

- **Inbound Rules:** Configure the inbound rules to allow traffic only from known and safe IP addresses or CIDR blocks.
- **Outbound Rules:** Restrict the outbound rules to only allow traffic to the necessary services, in this case, the RDS instance.

#### [Network Access Control Lists](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-network-acls.html) (NACLs):

Similarly to security groups, set up NACLs to control traffic at the subnet level, allowing only necessary traffic while denying all others by default.

#### [IAM Policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies.html):

Review and potentially update IAM roles and policies associated with your SageMaker Pipeline to adhere to the principle of least privilege, granting only the necessary permissions to perform the required tasks.

#### [Data Encryption](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/introduction-aws-security/data-encryption.html)

Make sure that data at rest and in transit is encrypted to maintain data confidentiality and security.

The goal remains to allow necessary communications to facilitate the functioning of your SageMaker Pipeline while ensuring that the environment remains secure.